# How to hook any API call on windows x64, x86?

Tags: windows, dll, kernel, hook, sandbox

I'm working on a way to hook any API call to perform some verification on the function. (I'm creating a SandBox)

The first way that I think about, is with register key, and implement our own dll into MicrosoftNT to be able to redirect any defined syscall. https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/160-apihooks .
Problem? only work on 32 bit, and if the binarie is loading User32.dll, so it's abig issue.

The second way is to inject a dll into a process? Simple but impossible, most program is defended from those injection, so it's not possible.

The last way that I think was to modify the SSDT to change the function address by mine and redirect to the original by creating a driver. Or by InlineHook and just modify the first byte of each address that I want.
The Problem, only working on 32 bit, because windows add a PatchGuard on the Kernel, so we can't do that.
We can delete de PatchGuard but, anticheat will notice the technique.

For the Sandbox I think it won't be a problem to delete a PatchGuard.

The main problem is for real time analysis, I have no more idea how I can do to hook every API call that I want, on any windows OS. I mean on 32 and 62 bit.
I'm a beginner in this domain I started this week so I'm open to any suggestion.

Comment: Maybe you need this: https://github.com/microsoft/detours

Comment: I already look some code about it, but we need to function address of the targeted binairie.. and you need to inject a DLL. As I said, CreateRemoteThread() will be rejected by protected program.  Or maybe I just don't understand how detours is working

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to hook every API call for a sandbox but then reference the SSDT? Those are two very different things. Do you want to hook VirtualQuery(Ex) or do you want to hook NtQueryVirtualMemory? From kernel or user mode? Or maybe you're referring to all loaded module exports as well as kernel system services?

**WinApi**

Iterate all loaded modules as well as installing an event to hook all future modules loaded. For each one you will iterate all exports and apply a hook of your preference which all jump to some handler. This handler should be raw assembly that preserves the CPU state, calls some method that does the logging and filtering, restores CPU state, before finally jumping to the original.

**Syscalls**

1. Disable Patchguard and apply hooks to every method in the service table similar to the WinApi method described above. This is definitely not suitable for production for obvious reasons.
2. Use an *instrumentation callback* which uses ZwSetInformationProcess to redirect most syscalls to an arbitrary assembly block. You can extract the syscall id here as well as parameters. Universal support is an issue though as it wasn't introduced until W7 iirc and you have a lot of limitations prior to W10.
3. Map a wrapper module that has a hook for every syscall into each newly loaded process from kernel. These hooks will apply to ntdll and simply invoke an NtDeviceIoControlFile call with the syscall id and arguments, forwarding it to your kernel driver for processing. This is commonly employed by antivirus software to monitor user mode system calls without disrupting Patchguard.
4. The most *approved* method would probably be callbacks. You can register process and thread callbacks in kernel, stripping handle access at your leisure. This will give you full control over process and thread access from external processes, and you can add a file minfilter to similarly restrict access to the file system.

Comment: When you call VirtualQuery, this function will call, NtQueryVirtualMemory, so if I want to make a Sandbox,I would hook Nt functions. I know hook api call for usermode and creating a driver to modfiy SSDT is diffirent but I just need to find a way to hook winApi of windows. I don't really understand the third and fourth solution that you gave to me. Do you have any ressource about the third one? For the callbacks method, how can you register process and threads callbacks in kernel? Thanks for your time.

Comment: ObRegisterCallbacks.